# cron not launching a working python script

Tags: python, cron, python-3.5, libraries

I have more than some troubles getting cron working on my raspberry pi 3b.
I wrote a python script and I have no issues launching it from thonny or terminal, it runs smoothly.

However, when launching the cron job in the following way (changing minutes and hours accordingly to test time):

```
25 21 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py >> /home/log/myscript.log 2>&1
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (more recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/main.py", line 9, in <module>
       import tweepy
ImportError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

No matter if I call `sudo crontab -e`, `nano crontab -e` or `cron -e`.
I started investigating and I guessed that there where problems with the python version to call.

Therefore I substituted the `python3` call with `python3.5`, later with `python3.5m` and even with `python3.8` with no results. In any attempt I tried launching the same command via terminal and it worked fine.
Tried to unistall and reinstall tweepy and checked the python used by Thonny which is the 3.5 version.

What can be trouble?
It's driving me mad.

**EDIT:**
I backed up my scripts and re-install raspberry pi to the latest version (5.10.17 linux kernel).
Again, I tried using the script with both Thonny and terminal and it run.

Again, I had the same problem using crontab.

However, I had an idea.
I updated the tweepy version to the latest version available, it was like a desperate attempt and something changed.

Instead of having the error related to tweepy,
cron gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/TwitterBot/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    a = soup.select('table > tr:has(> td > a:-soup-contains("San Pellegrino Terme")) td')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1376, in select
    return soupsieve.select(selector, self, namespaces, limit, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 112, in select
    return compile(select, namespaces, flags, **kwargs).select(tag, limit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 63, in compile
    return cp._cached_css_compile(pattern, namespaces, custom, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 205, in _cached_css_compile
    CSSParser(pattern, custom=custom_selectors, flags=flags).process_selectors(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1010, in process_selectors
    return self.parse_selectors(self.selector_iter(self.pattern), index, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 852, in parse_selectors
    has_selector, is_html = self.parse_pseudo_class(sel, m, has_selector, iselector, is_html)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 510, in parse_pseudo_class
    has_selector = self.parse_pseudo_open(sel, pseudo, has_selector, iselector, m.end(0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 654, in parse_pseudo_open
    sel.selectors.append(self.parse_selectors(iselector, index, flags))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 852, in parse_selectors
    has_selector, is_html = self.parse_pseudo_class(sel, m, has_selector, iselector, is_html)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 585, in parse_pseudo_class
    "'{}' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time".format(pseudo)
NotImplementedError: ':-soup-contains' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time
```

Which is a trouble related to the version of beautifulsup Cron is running.

I tried to update beautifulsup to the latest version available with no results.

I am starting to run out of idea,
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: from the terminal where the script works, for example if you run the script with `python3 main.py`, look at the output of `which python3`. Is it the same as in the cron job (`/usr/bin/python3`)?

Comment: yes, it is. the same path

Comment: excellent, then can you say which `crontab` you are using, the system-wide `/etc/crontab` or the user-specific one? As the user who can run the script well, you can do `crontab -e` to edit the user-specific one.

Comment: I believe to have the system wide one, thanks. Confirming as soon as I get home.
Also, I edited the question

Comment: if adding the command to the user's crontab with `crontab -e` will not work, then the next step should be to check whether the `sys.path` in the terminal and for the cronjob is the same. In your working terminal, can you run `python3 -m site` and note the output? Then run `crontab -e` and add `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 -m site > /home/out.txt` (or similar). Wait a minute and then compare the text in `out.txt` to the output from the previous command...

Comment: Did it.
The `sys.path = []` is the same. what differs is:
Terminal:
`USER BASE: '/home/pi//.local' (exists)`
`USER SITE: '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages' (exists)`

out.txt:
`USER BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)`
`USER SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages' (doesn't exist)`

Comment: update: tried to change the path for python in crontab so that it points to python3.8: `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`. this time the log file shows that the library to create problem is "requests" which I checked to be installed. it stops even earlier than using python3.5

Comment: @L.Grozinger I tried updating the whole raspberry and then updating tweepy and something changed but still stuck there.
In your opinion, what can be the next step from this point?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a virtual environment your paths in a shell script need to be for that virtual environment. Here's how I run shell on AWS linux instance. You can play around with this but it took me a while to figure it out. Maybe just add the long environment path in cron and skip the shell script.

This is inside my_shell.sh

```
/usr/local/bin/pipenv run ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ec2-user-zzkNbF-x/bin/python /home/ec2-user/my_path_to_file/my_file.py
```

This is my crontab setting

```
0 21 * * mon-fri /home/ec2-user/my_path_to_file/my_shell.sh
```

Comment: Thx Jonathan.
I will try it.
I am a noob ut maybe this is way to ahead for my game, I m not using a virtual environment.
Yet, I will give a try!

Comment: If you’re not using a virtual env, this isn’t your issue but finding the right paths is. But your error doesn’t sound like a cron issue per se. it’s about locating tweepy.

Comment: I managed to make tweepy work in cron but now is beautifulsoup the problem. Would you mind helping me in finding the right path? thx

Comment: Create a new question. Best to have the whole forum take a look for good solution.